# Launch processes one after another in C#

Tags: c#, process, foreach

Is there a way to iterate through an array/list and launch a process, and wait until it's exited until launching the next, and so on?

I have the code:

```
string[] processPaths = new string[]{ @"c:\foo.exe", @"c:\bar.exe" };
foreach(string s in processPaths){
    Process p = new Process();
    p.Exited += (obj, ev) => { continue; };
}
```

but obviously processes are executed asynchronously and the lambda function isn't part of the `foreach` loop. It's a console application, and I don't mind if it runs on the main thread.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`Process.WaitForExit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a4b407xt.aspx) is what you are looking for.

> Instructs the Process component to wait indefinitely for the associated process to exit.

Answer (score 3):

```
foreach (var name in names)
{
   var process = Process.Start(name);
   process.WaitForExit();
}
```